# c# datastructure to index value with DateTime

Tags: c#

I need to store data such that a `DateTime` value and a `float` value are stored together. A `Dictionary` is not useful because when retrieving data, I don't have the exact `DateTime` value. I just give the date(not the hour,min,second values) and have to get the `float` value/values corresponding to the date. What other datastructure can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to use DateTime. Also if you don't need the hours, etc. you can use only the date portion.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Then you could just create your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, float> dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, float>();
```

And access it with LINQ:

```
float value = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == dt).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `Dictionary<K,V>` with the date portion as the key and a `DateTime`/`float` tuple as the value?

Comment: I can have multiple entries for each day. I would have repetitive keys then

Comment: @Aks: You should've mentioned that in the question then, since it makes a big difference to the possible solutions.

Comment: @Aks: If you have multiple entries for the same date, then which float do you expect to get back?

Comment: Ok..I've solved this. I'm storing all entries for a day in a list and storing the date.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the functionality in a custom collection. The example I've provided is not in any way optimal, but it might give you an idea how to make your data easier to work with.

```
public sealed class DateTimeFloatDictionary : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<DateTime, float> _dictionary;

    public float this[DateTime index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary[index.Date];
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTimeFloatDictionary()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, float>();
    }

    public bool Contains(DateTime time)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(time.Date);
    }

    public void Add(DateTime time, float value)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(time.Date, value);
    }

    public bool Remove(DateTime time)
    {
        return _dictionary.Remove(time.Date);
    }

    #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime,float>> Members

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<DateTime, float>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, not tested though

```
 public class StrippedDate : IComparable<StrippedDate>, IComparable
{
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public StrippedDate(DateTime date)
    {

        Date = date;
    }


    public int CompareTo(StrippedDate other)
    {
        //you can simply compare
        if (Date.Year == other.Date.Year &&
            Date.Month == other.Date.Month &&
            Date.Day == other.Date.Day) return 0;
        //Put your logic to compare 
        return Date.CompareTo(other.Date);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //TODO:
        //Write better hash logic
        return Date.Year.GetHashCode() <<
               Date.Month.GetHashCode() <<
               Date.Month.GetHashCode() >> 0x41;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class StripedDateDictionary : IEnumerable<StrippedDate>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<StrippedDate, IList<float>> dictionary;

    public StripedDateDictionary(Dictionary<StrippedDate, IList<float>> dictionary)
    {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public void Add(StrippedDate key, float[] values)
    {

        dictionary.Add(key, new List<float>(values));

    }

    public float[] this[StrippedDate index]
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            /* set the specified index to value here */
        }
    }

    public float[] this[DateTime time]
    {
        get
        {
            StrippedDate date = new StrippedDate(time);
            return this[date];
        }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException("Setter not implemented"); }
    }
    public IEnumerator<StrippedDate> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dictionary.Select(pair => pair.Key).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```